# Bug in Expected Functional Rule in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to solve a problem about a gun that has two options of damage (option:s, option:c). Option s gives damage D and option c doubles the current damage into 2*D. The way the rule is structured is this :

```
evaluate_damage(D,List,TotalDamage).
```

D is the initial damage.

List is a list that has a compilation of s and c.

TotalDamage is the total damage that is caused from the List.

Here are some examples.

```
?- evaluate_damage(1, [s,s], TotalDamage).
TotalDamage = 2
Yes

?- evaluate_damage(1, [s,c,s,c], TotalDamage).
TotalDamage = 3
Yes

?- evaluate_damage(1, [s,c,s,c,s,s], TotalDamage).
TotalDamage = 11
Yes

?- evaluate_damage(2, [s,s], TotalDamage).
TotalDamage = 4
Yes
```

It works perfectly fine on its own but when I use it inside an another rule, it doesn't give the expected result. Specifically, I have an other rule in my program that rearranges the order of the chars to achieve less of a damage.
The way this rule is structured is this:

```
hack(List,Max,NewProgram,N).
```

Where List is the list of the elements.
Max is the maximum damage the rearranged list will cause.
NewProgram is the rearranged list,

N is the number of the swaps done to get to the rearranged list NewProgram.

Here are expected results of this rule:

```
?- hack([c, s], 1, NewProgram, N).
NewProgram = [s, c]
N = 1
Yes
?- hack([s, s], 1, NewProgram, N).
No
?- hack([s, c, c, s, s, c], 6, NewProgram, N).
NewProgram = [s, s, c, c, s, c]
N = 2
Yes
?- hack([c, s, c, s, s], 3, NewProgram, N).
NewProgram = [s, s, s, c, c]
N = 5
Yes
```

This is my code.

```
evaluate_damage(_,[],0).
evaluate_damage(D,s,D).
evaluate_damage(D,c,Damage) :-
  Damage is D*2.
evaluate_damage(D,[H|List],TotalDamage) :- 
    evaluate_damage(D,H,Damage),
    (Damage=D;Damage=0),
    evaluate_damage(D,List,TDamage),
    TotalDamage is D+TDamage.
evaluate_damage(D,[H|List],TotalDamage) :-
    evaluate_damage(D,H,Damage),
    Damage>D,
    evaluate_damage(Damage,List,TotalDamage).

cutList(List,List1,[c|List2]) :- 
    append(List1,[c|List2], List),!.

hack(List,Max,NewProgram,N) :-
    cutList(List,L1,[c|L2]),
    length(L2,Length2),
    append(L2,c,NewList2),
    append(L1,NewList2,NewList),
    evaluate_damage(1,NewList,SecondDamage),
    SecondDamage=<Max,
    N is Length2,
    NewProgram is NewList.
```

The actual output is

```
?- hack([c, s], 1, NewProgram, N).
No (0.00s cpu)
```

I debugged it through tracer (option in Tools - tkEclipse) and the problem is that when

```
evaluate_damage(D,Program,TotalDamage)
```

is called inside

```
hack(Program,Max,NewProgram,N)
```

it doesn't give the expected output. That's really odd because when 
    evaluate_damage(D,Program,TotalDamage)

is called by its own, it works perfect. Does anybody know what is the problem?

Comment: What do you think `N is Length2` and `NewProgram is NewList` are doing for you? You could replace `N` and `NewProgram` with `Length2` and `NewList` in the head and the program would mean the same thing to Prolog, but would that make it look wrong to you?

Comment: The reason why I wrote it like that is because I wanted to make some changes with my code and maybe add a second rule. Right now my main concern is the bug I have. I changed my code and tried it in the way you suggested. It doesn't change something but it's more simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
...
append(L2,c,NewList2),
...
```

the second argument of append must be a list.

and is/2 doesn't 'copy' a value from right to left. Use variables in the head or the unification operator =/2. Take seriously Daniel' suggestion about reconsidering your code after renames.

Overall, you're progressing well into Prolog.
Of course, there are libraries in modern Prolog systems that could shorten the code a lot. But the pedagogical value gained solving basic problems is invaluable.